# Google Consent Mode Implementation using Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby, google-tag-manager

I am following this [tutorial](https://support.cookieinformation.com/en/articles/5411279-google-consent-mode-implementation)  about implementing google consent mode to add cookies to my website !
By using Gatsby.js I am not sure how to add these codes :

```
<!-- The initial config of Consent Mode -->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('consent', 'default', {
ad_storage: 'denied',
analytics_storage: 'denied',
wait_for_update: 1500,
});
gtag('set', 'ads_data_redaction', true);
</script>
​
<!-- Cookie Information Pop-up Script is required for the SDK -->
<script id="CookieConsent" src="https://policy.app.cookieinformation.com/uc.js" data-culture="EN" type="text/javascript"></script>
​
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TRACKING-ID"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
​
gtag('config', 'TRACKING-ID');
</script>
​
</head>
<body>
```

Do you have any idea how to implement this code in Gatsby , is there any library or something that will help to implement these scripts !
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component is used as the initial screen that applies when the page loads.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { useLocation } from '@reach/router';
import { initializeAndTrack } from 'gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import CookieSettings from './Settings';

const CookieBanner = () => {
    const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(false);
    const [showSettings, setShowSettings] = useState(false);
    const location = useLocation();

    // showSettings -> use this state property to open a configuration
    // window which may open up more information on the cookie(s) being applied

    useEffect(() => {
        setShowBanner(Cookies.get('gatsby-gdpr-responded') !== 'true');
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        initTracking();
    }, [Cookies.get('gatsby-gdpr-responded')])

    const initTracking = () => {
        initializeAndTrack(location)
    }

    const handleAccept = () => {
        Cookies.set('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics', true, { expires: 365 })
        handleCloseAll();
    }

    const handleDecline = () => {
        Cookies.remove('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics');
        handleCloseAll();
    }

    const handleCloseAll = () => {
        setShowSettings(false);
        setShowBanner(false);

        Cookies.set('gatsby-gdpr-responded', true, { expires: 365 });
    }

    return (
        // add your component logic here
        // Take not of the different functions that are available above, like handleAccept / handleDecline / handleCloseAll 
        // handleCloseAll -> if a user declines / closes the banner
        // handleAccept -> a button to accept by default
        // handleDecline -> a button to decline the cookies

    )
}

export default CookieBanner
```

The next component is more of a Configuration screen, which provides more information on the cookies being applied, if you take note on the import of Toggle, we use a toggle to allow users to specifically toggle on or off their cookies at any point, you of course if you have many GDPR compliances, may want to either create separate functions that handle the removal of cookies or a reusable function that is passed the name of the cookie to be removed / applied.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import Button from '@components/Button';
import Toggle from '@components/Inputs/Toggle';

const CookieSettings = ({
    handleAccept,
    handleDecline,
    initTracking,
    handleCloseAll
}) => {
    const [trackAnalytics, setTrackAnalytics] = useState(Cookies.get('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics') === 'true')

    const handleToggle = () => {
        Cookies.set('gatsby-gdpr-responded', true, { expires: 365 });

        setTrackAnalytics((prevState) => {
            if (prevState) {
                Cookies.remove('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics');
            } else {
                Cookies.set('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics', true, { expires: 365 })
            }

            return !prevState
        })

        initTracking();
    }

    return (
        // your JSX code here
    )
}

export default CookieSettings;
```

## EDIT

```js
// A some what reusable function that you can pass a cookie name too and switch over the name provided and set the required cookie.
const handleToggle = (cookieName) => {
        Cookies.set('gatsby-gdpr-responded', true, { expires: 365 });

        switch (cookieName) {
            case 'gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics':
                return setTrackAnalytics((prevState) => {
                    if (prevState) {
                        Cookies.remove(cookieName);
                    } else {
                        Cookies.set(cookieName, true, {
                            expires: 365
                        });
                    }

                    return !prevState
                })
            case 'gatsby-gdpr-google-tagmanager':
                return setTagAnalytics((prevState) => {
                    if (prevState) {
                        Cookies.remove(cookieName);
                    } else {
                        Cookies.set(cookieName, true, {
                            expires: 365
                        });
                    }

                    return !prevState
                })
            case 'gatsby-gdpr-facebook-pixel':
                return setFacebookAnalytics((prevState) => {
                    if (prevState) {
                        Cookies.remove(cookieName);
                    } else {
                        Cookies.set(cookieName, true, {
                            expires: 365
                        });
                    }

                    return !prevState
                })
            default:
                break;
        }

        initTracking()
    }
```

```js
// A JSX toggle within your cookie setting
<Toggle active={trackAnalytics} toggleActive={() => handleToggle('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics')} />
```

```js
// The toggle component itself
import React from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import './styles.scss';

export default function Toggle({
    active = false,
    toggleActive,
}) {

    return (
        <div onClick={typeof toggleActive === 'function' && toggleActive} className={cx('toggle relative cursor-pointer', { active })} />
    )
}


Toggle.propTypes = {
    active: PropTypes.bool,
    toggleActive: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

Toggle.defaultProps = {
    active: false,
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer ,  my question is how can I mark each user option , something like this https://i.ibb.co/7nJvPJX/Screenshot-7.png

Comment: So functional cookies do not need to be accepted/decline, so long as they are required  for the "core" functionality of the website. Such as within Wordpress for instance, they require certain cookies for core functionality to work without hindering experience.

Comment: The other two would need to be as mentioned above, they are of your own choosing whether they are google analytics / tag manager or another platform that you pass to your GDPR cookie plugin. 
You would need to follow the code above where `gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics` would be "one" of your cookies, and either create a reusable function that creates/deletes cookies on click of a toggle component. The code is provided above, its up to you to take it and change it as required :)

Comment: I will edit the reply to show you a switch version of this

Comment: Have provided you an abundance of code for logic and a component for a toggle, its up to you to crack the rest of the code :)

Comment: Much appreciated sir ! this is the most detailed answer ever , Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin from the Gatsby Plugin Hub
`gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`

It will provide you what you are looking for and also you can list in the options for the plugin which cookies you are looking to track + a cookieName you wish to provide which you can then work with from a component level when creating a cookie toolbar such as:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`,
  options: {
    googleAnalytics: {
      trackingId: process.env.UA_TAG, // your UA tag goes here
      cookieName: `gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics`,
      anonymize: true,
      allowAdFeatures: false
    },
    environments: [`production`, `development`]
  },
},
```

It elimites the usage of having to inject a script into the head of the website with React-Helmet as the plugin will handle the script injection for you.

Comment: Thanks ! Concerning the Cookie  component I am not sure how to make a customized one ? any idea ?

Comment: Of course - let me add another answer for you so i have more characters, although i will omit most things as your styling + component set up for JSX is up to you, but the fundemental functions ill provide

Comment: I appreciate you support !!

Comment: No problem, I have added it as a new answer